# JS Differnce Between Inputed times

Tags: javascript, time

I would like to prompt(); 3 times once for hour then minute then seconds. Then the user has to supply a date the same way which must be less then the other one. Then print the difference. How could this be acomplished in js? I couldn't really find anything for prompting to date on google nor stackoverflow. (Only some similar ones which don't cover my situation.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Dates</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script>

    function Beolvas(){
                    do{
                var a = parseFloat(prompt("Hour"));
            }while(isNaN(a)||(a>24)||(a<0));
                    do{
                var b = parseFloat(prompt("Min"));
            }while(isNaN(b)||(b>60)||(b<0));
                    do{
                var c = parseFloat(prompt("Sec"));
            }while(isNaN(c)||(c>60)||(c<0));
                    do{
                var d = parseFloat(prompt("Hour2"));
            }while(isNaN(d)||(d>24)||(d<0));
                    do{
                var e = parseFloat(prompt("Min2"));
            }while(isNaN(e)||(e>60)||(e<0));
                    do{
                var f = parseFloat(prompt("Sec2"));
            }while(isNaN(f)||(f>60)||(f<0));
            //How?
            var dif = 0;
         document.getElementById("k").innerHTML= diff;
    }

 </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Thing</h1>

<button onclick="Beolvas()">Input</button>

<p id="k"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want to "print" the date? In the console? In a web page? Could you add a snippet of code of your what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Here's how to prompt. You can ask for dates like this too. Just get them as numbers, makes it easier to substract and calculate the difference.

Comment: Thanks but I mainly have problems with the difference calculation.

Comment: Do you have problems subtracting the numbers? That would simply be `var seconds = f-c`